# Is there an app that can make another app run solely from the menubar?

Tags: macos

I've got an app that I need to leave running, but I never do anything *with* - it's essentially a server. I'd like some way to either hide it completely from the dock and (if possible) put it up in the menubar (top-right) out of the way of CMD+Tab.

Are there any apps that can do this for me?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [**Spirited Away**](http://www.macupdate.com/info.php/id/15844) - it can automatically hide inactive applications or you can hide them yourself whenever you wish:

[image]

**You can also hide it with AppleScript:**

```
tell application "System Events"
    set visible of process "Your App Name Here" to false
end tell
```

...**or run it as a** [**daemon**](http://mac.softpedia.com/get/System-Utilities/daemonize.shtml).

Comment: Now that's interesting... never occured to me, but with your suggestion I could create an applescript to launch it and then hide it on login. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of any apps, but to do it manually isn't too hard:

1. Find the app you want to open in the Finder.
2. Right click » Show Package Contents
3. Open the Contents folder.
4. Open Info.plist in a text editor.
5. Change the last two lines:

   ```
   </dict>
   </plist>
   ```

   To look like this:

   ```
   <key>LSUIElement</key>
   <true/>
   </dict>
   </plist>
   ```
6. Reboot.

I think there's a drawback to this under certain situations, but I can't remember what it is. I'm sure someone would be happy to oblige…

Comment: Whenever the app is updated, you have to do it again. | You sure you have to reoot to make it work?

Answer (score 0):

[Dock Dodger](http://foggynoggin.com/dockdodger), and one other I can't remember at the moment. I like Dock Dodger better, though.